# Maximising Collidable area for a hexagonal "Button" in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, hexagonal-tiles

I am programming a strategy game that takes place on an Hexagonal grid (yes, a civ clone) and want to implement a system, which allows me to display some properties of the tile by hovering over it with my mouse. My current implementation is to create a rect for every Tile (1), this rect has the same dimensions and coordinates as the sprite of the Tile. Then, I use pygame.Rect.collidepoint (2) to detect collision. The problem with this is that the rects of the different Tiles overlap at the edges, causing multiple collisions to be detected (3)

(1)

```
for i in range (0, 100):
    Tiles_rects.append (pygame.Rect(Tiles_pos[i], (TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT )))
```

(2)

```
for i in range (0, 100):
            # Takes one tile at a time and determines if mouse is on top of it
            mouse_over_tile = pygame.Rect.collidepoint( Tiles_rects[i] , mouse_pos )    
            if mouse_over_tile:
                print (i)    #placeholder
```

[(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E9SN.gif)

[image]

I tried to make the colliders (rects) smaller and adjusted their position to be centered. While this does fix the overlap, it also makes a considerable part of the hexagon not react when hovered over. A circle collider instead of a rect collider would likely not be of much more use, as my hexagons are somewhat streched on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the slope on the sides of the hexagon is 60°. If the y-distance to the center of the bounding rectangle is less than the x-distance from the outside of the bounding rectangle multiplied by the tangent of 60°, the point is inside the hexagon:

```py
def collideHexagon(bounding_rect, position):
    px, py = position
    if bounding_rect.collidepoint((px, py)):
        dx = min(px - bounding_rect.left, bounding_rect.right - px)
        dy = abs(py - bounding_rect.centery)
        if dy < dx * math.tan(math.radians(60)):
            return True
    return False
```

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


len = 100
sin_len = math.sin(math.radians(60)) * len
cos_len = math.cos(math.radians(60)) * len
pts = [
    (len, 0), (len-cos_len, sin_len), (cos_len-len, sin_len),
    (-len, 0), (cos_len-len, -sin_len), (len-cos_len, -sin_len)]
pts = [(x + 200, y + 200) for x, y in pts]

tile_heihgt = sin_len * 2
tile_width = len * 2
tiel_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, tile_width, tile_heihgt)
tiel_rect.center = (200, 200)

def collideHexagon(bounding_rect, position):
    px, py = position
    if bounding_rect.collidepoint((px, py)):
        dx = min(px - bounding_rect.left, bounding_rect.right - px)
        dy = abs(py - bounding_rect.centery)
        if dy < dx * math.tan(math.radians(60)):
            return True
    return False

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    color = "white"
    if collideHexagon(tiel_rect, pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        color = "red"
 
    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, pts)         
    pygame.display.flip() 

pygame.quit()
exit()
```